# How to disable HTTP pipelining from iOS5 devices to a regular website

Tags: http, webview, ios5

One of my clients is having a problem with their web service ever since iOS5 came out. Their service (an HTTP api) reacts weirdly to HTTP pipelining calls and it will take a few days to fix it. Is there any meta or HTTP response setting I can set in my website to disable this feature when iOS5 devices browse to my page? This is a standard web application and not a native app.

I Googled to no prevail. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using NSURLConnection or CFHTTPStream ?

Comment: Hi Nikita, this is a web application that uses an HTTP api, not a native app. Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: How about using a NSURLConnection to download webpage then give local html to webView ? NSURLConnection doesn't pipeline HTTP calls. Using ASIWebPageRequest may also be an option but it uses CFHTTP calls which uses HTTP pipelining not sure about ASIHTTPRequests look at their source code.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking how to turn off Pipelining in MobileSafari.app, is this the case?

Comment: Yes, this is just a standard web app accessed via mobile safari browser.